# changing splash screen, duplicate splash screen

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen

I deleted previous splash image and added new splash image in XCode, but when I start app the first it show previous splash image (like it is not deleted) and after that new splash image? I also checked Launch screen.xib file and there is just new splash screen image, but app still showing first the deleted one image and new after that on startup of app. I rebuild application few times, but no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To fix your issue: Clean project (in Xcode), delete derived data (in Finder). Google if you do not know how.

Comment: I have done that few times, but still same thing is happening :(

Comment: Than delete the app from device/ simulator.

Comment: Done that, still the same

Comment: Impossible. If you did all this, there can not be a cached outdated image. Conclusion: a) you did not do all this b) old image still exists in Xcode. I the later case, we need more information.

Comment: I done all staff which you mention few time, but always the problem is same. I am 100% sure that the old splash image is deleted, because I searched whole mac and XCode project directory for that image (no result). The old image appear on startup of app, and the real one is programmatically set in  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method (Launch Screen.storyboard - >view is set for rootviewcontroller) so after that the splash screen got correct image. The old image doesn't exist in project files, I don't know how that image can still be shown on app

Comment: Try in mentioned order: Run in simulator. Stop. Reset Simulator, clean project, delete derived data. Run in simulator. If the problem persists, the root of your problem (the old image) is in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and thanks everyone for help. 
I am not really sure what is happening with project, I can not change splash screen after cleaning and rebuilding whole process. My solution was to delete an existing splash screen and create another one with different name, that I initialize later in my code, and it works.

Answer (score 4):

First of all replace or change all your splash screens in your project. Run the app in your device or simulator. If problem occurred then follow these steps:

1. Clean the xcode and run the app.
2. If step 1 not work, after cleaning quit the Xcode and again start, follow step 1.
3. If still problem occurring, delete the app from your device or simulator and follow the steps 1 and 2. (Sometimes our device need to restart in this case, if required then do this also)

As I have faced same and I followed these steps and my problem solved.